# Different accuracy on same CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have this CNN:

```
def cnn(trainImages, trainLabels, testImages, testLabels):
    trainImages = np.array(trainImages)
    trainLabels = np.array(trainLabels)
    testImages = np.array(testImages)
    testLabels = np.array(testLabels)

    trainImages = trainImages / 255
    testImages = testImages / 255

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', input_shape = (224, 224, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(9))

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True), metrics = ['accuracy'])

    model.fit(trainImages, trainLabels, epochs = 10)

    predictionResult = model.predict(testImages)

    pred = []
    for i in range(len(predictionResult)):
        pred.append(np.argmax(predictionResult[i], axis = -1))

    print('Accuracy: ', metrics.accuracy_score(testLabels, pred))

    print(metrics.classification_report(testLabels, pred))

    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(testLabels, pred))
```

1). I got different accuracy everytime when I run the CNN, between 87% and 93%. How can I get permanently when I run the same accuracy? I tried `tensorflow.set_random_seed()`, but without effect.

2). What should I improve at my network to get over 95%? Input has shape (224, 224, 3). 2831 training images and 665 testing. 9 output classes. A problem of color recognition.

Comment: 1) Are you using GPUs or CPUs for the training? With GPUs, cuda could produce some variability even if you set the random seed. Try
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1" and setting the seed to a fixed value. The second point should not be posted here since it's a theorical question. Maybe look for some good model in the state of the art

Comment: I'm using GPU. It works, but my epochs take longer now, from 7s to 61. Why? What does os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"?

Comment: @FaneSpoitoru `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"` Basically hides the GPU from the TensorFlow and hence your model will train on CPU and hence you should never ever do that. For further detail on the topic you should read [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14812/making-keras-tensorflow-code-execution-deterministic-on-a-gpu).

Comment: @jackve If you are posting an answer and if it has some consequences then you must post them as well especially in this case when the consequence of setting that environment variable to -1 is huge.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in a comment, one possibility for such a behavior is the use of GPUs: cuda introduces some little variability and therefore you could experience some fluctuations in the accuracy of two models trained it the same way. You could try to disable the GPU:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

And setting the seed as before. However, this would limit your performance and you will need more time to complete the same training, since you would use only CPUs and not your GPU

Comment: There is any method to use GPU and the accuracy be the same?

Comment: Not that I know, but please check that your "problem" is actually the use of the GPU